# Search and count a word from a string

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I need a way to look for a word in a file only using `length()`, `charAt()`, `toUpperCase()`, and `toLowerCase()` methods.

In the long run, I'm using this for a file but for practice, I'm going to use a simple string.

This is what I have to far:

```
public class WordSearch
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    String str = "This is a sentence I am using as an example example Example.";
    String word = "example";
    int wordCounter = 1;

        for(int i; i < str.length(); i++)
       {
        if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
            wordCounter++; 
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: curiosity.. its a project kind of well part of it anyway. All of the String and StringBuilder methods I want to use I can't use them at all. I know I have to use a for loop but can't figure out how

Answer (score 1):

```
 String text = "This is a ship shipping-ship,  shipping  shipping ships";
    String word = "shipping"; 
    String text1 = text.contains(" " + word + " ") ? text.replace(" " + word + " ", "") : text;
    System.out.println((text.length() - text1.length()) / word.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general overview on how to do it while conforming to your requirements.

- Load the file into memory as a string. Make the file string and word string both lowercase.
- Create a counter that will track how much of the word has been found. Set it to `0` initially
- Loop from the first character to the last character. If the character you're on matches the first character of your word increment the counter. Then for the next character see if it matches the second character of the word, if so increment the counter again, and so on. If the characters do not match reset the counter to `0` When your counter equals the word length you have found the word.

**Note:** Using a scanner and reading char by char is a much more memory efficient way of accomplishing this task.

Comment: I sort of get what you're saying... Am I making nested for loops or multiple if statements...